# Import 100 million rows to MS SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a service that will sometimes import 100 million rows from csv file to database.

My code works very **slow** (0.5 seconds for every request) and I have to make many requests.

I have two columns, they are both a primary keys. Therefore it can be so slow because of indexing. 
But if I make an import using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (import wizard) - it works very fast.

Is there a way to make it faster or with fewer requests?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    long i = 0;
    string result = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string s = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] data = s.Split(',');

        sb.Append(string.Format("('{0}',{1}),", data[0], data[1]));

        i++;
        if (i % 1000 == 0)
        {
            result = sb.ToString();

            string queryString = "USE[PassportExpiredTestBase]\r\n" +
                                 "INSERT INTO[dbo].[PassportList]([Series],[Number])VALUES" +
                                 result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // The most expensive operation

            sb.Clear();
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can do bulk inserts i.e. 1k at a time or something like that.

Comment: why dont you use ssms import wzard ? it is much faster than c#

Comment: @Arash, I can't because I have to do it every day at night

Comment: @SatishGarg, thank you, I've made with Bulk Insert and DataSet and it works great!

Comment: Well , In this case i Would Design Data Tranfrom Package Using  SSIS And Then Use Sql Agent To Run it within Specific Interval.

Comment: @Arash thanks! It's the best way!

Comment: would you so please up vote my comment . thanks

Comment: @Arash unfortunately I can't do it because of reputation :(